# How to optimize ODE parameter fitting?

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, nonlinear, modeling

Consider the data

```
times = {0, 5, 9, 18, 28, 38};
adata = Transpose[{times, {45, 52, 56, 45, 42, 44}}];
bdata = Transpose[{times, {91, 110, 125, 105, 88, 84}}];
cdata = Transpose[{times, {12677, 12305, 12767, 12021, 11693, 11321}}];
```

I want to optimize the parameters $k_0,k_1,k_2,p_0,p_1,p_2>0$ for the system
$$
\begin{align}
a'(t)&=p_0-k_0a(t)\\
b'(t)&=p_1 a(t)-k_1b(t)\\
c'(t)&=p_2b(t)-k_2c(t)
\end{align}
$$
The following code does not converge

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
    a'[t] == -k0 a[t] + p0,
    b'[t] == -k1 b[t] + p1 a[t],
    c'[t] == -k2 c[t] + p2 b[t],
    a[0] == adata[[1, 2]], b[0] == bdata[[1, 2]], c[0] == cdata[[1, 2]]
    }, {a, b, c}, {t, 0, 38}, {k0, k1, k2, p0, p1, p2}];

Clear[model];
model[k0_?NumericQ, k1_?NumericQ, k2_?NumericQ, p0_?NumericQ, 
  p1_?NumericQ, p2_?NumericQ] :=
 Sum[
    (sol[k0, k1, k2, p0, p1, p2][[1]][times[[i]]] - adata[[i, 2]])^2 + 
    (sol[k0, k1, k2, p0, p1, p2][[2]][times[[i]]] - bdata[[i, 2]])^2 +
    (sol[k0, k1, k2, p0, p1, p2][[3]][times[[i]]] - cdata[[i, 2]])^2,
    {i, Length@bdata}]

fit = Values@
  Last@NMinimize[{model[k0, k1, k2, p0, p1, p2], 
     Thread[(# > 0 &)[{k0, k1, k2, p0, p1, p2}]]}, {k0, k1, k2, p0, 
     p1, p2}]
```

Is there a more efficient of fitting this model? Also, would there exist a reasonable way to pick the initial conditions?

Comment: This system is exactly solvable with `DSolve`. Try fitting your data to the exact solution. However, note that your approach is also slightly ... sketchy, because you are forcing your initial values to be exactly the same as your data.

Comment: @Domen what would better initial conditions be?

Comment: A better approach would be to use `DSolve` with the initial conditions $a_0, b_0, c_0$ as unknown variables (along with the $k_i$ and $p_i$ values.)  Then optimize over $\{a_0, b_0, c_0, k_i, p_i\}$ using `NonLinearModelFit`.  If I have time this afternoon I'll try to mock something up.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thank you! That would be extremely useful!

Comment: Also, do you mean "2000 data points" or "2000 evolving variables in the ODE system"?  That's going to make a difference in the viability of the method I'm describing.

Comment: I realize I made a mistake (shouldn't be pairs). Essentially, I have data to fit around 2000 3-equation systems of ODEs (independent of each other). This was merely a comment to show that I want an efficient fitting algorithm (if possible), without requiring high-performance computing

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you have about 2000 sets of data points of the form {t, a, b, c} and you'll need to run the code on each one of them.  How big is each set of data points?  (Also, finding 2000 reasonable initial guesses for `NonLinearModelFit` may be an issue, though I won't know until I've actually tried it out.)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The time points are the same for all sets. For now, I would be happy with just an efficient optimisation for the single system with the data provided above.

Comment: Why do you expect your `model` is the right one?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I have made a [new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/293101/optimizing-an-ode-fitting-algorithm), which tackles the optimization problem with the interpolation assumption. It would be great if you could take a look! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Same idea as proposed by @Michael Seifert(thanks)

```
 {sola, solb, solc} = 
 Values@DSolve [{a'[t] == -k0 a[t] + p0, b'[t] == -k1 b[t] + p1 a[t], 
 c'[t] == -k2 c[t] + p2 b[t], a[0] == a0, b[0] == b0, 
 c[0] == c0}, {a, b, c}, t] // Flatten
```

model(I scaled the cdata because it's factor 100 greater)

```
J = Sum[(sola [times[[i]]] - adata[[i, 2]])^2 + (solb  [times[[i]]] -bdata[[i, 2]])^2 + 
1/100  ^2 (solc [times[[i]]] - cdata[[i, 2]])^2, {i,Length@bdata}];
fit = NMinimize[J, {k0, k1, k2, p0, p1, p2, a0, b0, c0}]
(*{38564.8, {k0 -> 0.419621, k1 -> 2.10042, k2 -> 0.139004, 
p0 -> 12.062, p1 -> 8.24167, p2 -> 16.0036, a0 -> 7.49045, 
b0 -> 3.05036, c0 -> 2.79384}}*)
```

But the fit is poor

```
Show[{ListPlot[adata], Plot[sola[t] /. fit[[2]], {t, 0, 38}]},PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Show[{ListPlot[bdata], Plot[solb[t] /. fit[[2]], {t, 0, 38}]},PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
Show[{ListPlot[cdata], Plot[solc[t] /. fit[[2]], {t, 0, 38}]},PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed it is a poor fit. What if instead we replace `a[t]` as an interpolation of `adata`? Can we improve the results? Would the `DSolve` approach still hold? Or perhaps changing it to an equation whose solution better fits the data? In fact, the equation that holds for $a$ is arbitrary. Would it be possible to improve this with your method?

Comment: @samwolfe What means *In fact, the equation that holds for a is arbitrary* ?

Comment: The dynamics for the data $a$ are not really known. Ideally I would like $a$ to be closer to the data, than a mere exponential function, which is the case with my system. Perhaps I should have phrased it differently but, any ideas? I mentioned interpolation because it could be a good fitting approach