# Optimizing an ODE fitting algorithm with interpolated data

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, fitting, modeling

Given data, I want to find parameters $p_1,p_2,k_1,k_2>0$ that fit the following ODE system
$$
\begin{align}
b'(t)&=p_1 a(t)-k_1b(t)\\
c'(t)&=p_2b(t)-k_2c(t)
\end{align}
$$
where $a(t)$ is an interpolation of data `adata`. We also have the datasets `bdata` and `cdata`. Considering we have 6 data points for each $a$, $b$ and $c$, at time points `times`, I believe the following code, does what I want:

```
times = {0, 5, 9, 18, 28, 38};

adata = Transpose[{times, {0.24, 0.71, 0.95, 0.26, 0.05, 0.22}}];
bdata = Transpose[{times, {0.2, 0.62, 0.95, 0.51, 0.13, 0.05}}];
cdata = Transpose[{times, {0.89, 0.66, 0.95, 0.49, 0.28, 0.05}}];
data = Join[Table[Flatten@{1, bdata[[i]]}, {i, Length@times}], 
   Table[Flatten@{2, cdata[[i]]}, {i, Length@times}]];

interp = Interpolation[
   Transpose[{times, {0.24, 0.71, 0.95, 0.26, 0.05, 0.22}}], 
   Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 2];

tmax = times[[-1]];
ode = {
   b'[t] == p1 interp[t] - k1 b[t],
   c'[t] == p2 b[t] - k2 c[t],
   b[0] == bdata[[1, 2]], c[0] == cdata[[1, 2]] 
   }; 

paramSOL = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[ode, {b, c}, {t, 0, tmax}, {k1, k2, p1, p2}];
Clear[model];
model[k1_, k2_, p1_, p2_][i_, t_] := 
  Through[paramSOL[k1, k2, p1, p2][t], List][[i]] /; 
   And @@ NumericQ /@ {k1, k2, p1, p2, i, t};
fitted = NonlinearModelFit[
    data, {model[k1, k2, p1, p2][i, t], 
     Thread[(# > 0 &)[{k1, k2, p1, p2}]]}, {{k1, 0.1}, {k2, 0.1}, {p1,
       0.1}, {p2, 0.1}}, {i, t}] // Quiet;
err = Total[(bdata[[All, 2]] - (fitted[1, #] & /@ times))^2 + (cdata[[
        All, 2]] - (fitted[2, #] & /@ times))^2];

solutions = {interp, fitted[1, #] &, fitted[2, #] &};
results = {adata, bdata, cdata};
titles = {"a", "b", "c"};
Grid[{
  Table[Show[
    Plot[solutions[[j]][x], {x, 0, 38}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotLabel -> titles[[j]]], 
    ListPlot[results[[j]], PlotStyle -> Red]], {j, 3}]}]
```

[image]

However, this is **incredibly slow**. Can I do better? Is there a way of optimising this code, perhaps with `DSolve`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do the fitting.

1 - We will using a custom-made second order interpolation as giving in `f[t]`. A dummy extra data point was introduced to facilitate the piecewise interpolating function definition.

2 - We will using a symbolic `DSolve` that can be cope with a family of analogous ODE's with same time grid. A model including a symbolic time grid can be used. I leave it as an exercise.

3 - We will be fitting all the functions $\{a(t),b(t),c(t)\}$ at the same time.

4 - We will consider initial conditions as parameters to determine (`b0`, `c0`).

Some additional considerations. The data set is small as pointed by @Eric Brown. This facilitates an undesirable over-fitting. To avoid non-negativeness in $\{a(t),b(t),c(t)\}$ restrictions of type $\{a(t_k) > 0, b(t_k) > 0, c(t_k) > 0\}$ may be introduced in the minimization process, which will delay the command elapsed time.

```
tk = {0, 5, 9, 18, 28, 38};
tk0 = Join[tk, {tk[[6]] + 10}];
n = Length[tk0];
ak = 10 {0.24, 0.71, 0.95, 0.26, 0.05, 0.22};
ak0 = Join[ak, {ak[[6]]}];
bk = 10 {0.2, 0.62, 0.95, 0.51, 0.13, 0.05};
bk0 = Join[bk, {bk[[6]]}];
ck = 10 {0.89, 0.66, 0.95, 0.49, 0.28, 0.05};
ck0 = Join[ck, {ck[[6]]}];
adata = Transpose[{tk, ak}];
bdata = Transpose[{tk, bk}];
cdata = Transpose[{tk, ck}];

equs1 = Table[u[k] + a[k] (tk0[[k + 1]] - tk0[[k]]) + b[k] (tk0[[k + 1]] - tk0[[k]])^2 - u[k + 1], {k, 1, n - 1}];
equs2 = Table[a[k] + 2 b[k] (tk0[[k + 1]] - tk0[[k]]) - a[k + 1], {k, 1, n - 1}];
equs = Join[equs1, equs2];
vars = Join[Table[a[k], {k, 1, n - 1}], Table[b[k], {k, 1, n - 1}]];
sols = Solve[equs == 0, vars][[1]];

f[t_] := Piecewise[Table[{u[k] + a[k] (t - tk0[[k]]) + b[k] (t - tk0[[k]])^2, tk0[[k + 1]] >= t >= tk0[[k]]}, {k, 1, n - 1}]]
ft = f[t] /. sols /. {a[7] -> 0, u[7] -> 0};

ode = {b'[t] == p1 ft - k1 b[t], c'[t] == p2 b[t] - k2 c[t], b[0] == b0, c[0] == c0};
{bt, ct} = {b[t], c[t]} /. DSolve[ode, {b, c}, t][[1]];

{bt0, ct0} = {bt, ct} /. Table[tau[k] -> tk0[[k]], {k, 1, n}];
ft0 = ft /. Table[tau[k] -> tk0[[k]], {k, 1, n}];
obj = Sum[((bk0[[k]] - bt0)^2 + (ck0[[k]] - ct0)^2 + (ak0[[k]] - ft0)^2) /. {t -> tk0[[k]]}, {k, 1, 7}];
sol = NMinimize[obj, {k1, k2, p1, p2, u[1], u[2], u[3], u[4], u[5], u[6], b0, c0}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

{bt00, ct00} = {bt0, ct0} /. sol[[2]];
at0 = ft0 /. sol[[2]];

Show[ListPlot[Transpose[{tk, ak}], PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}], 
     Plot[at0, {t, tk[[1]], tk[[6]]}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}], PlotRange -> All]
Show[ListPlot[Transpose[{tk, bk}], PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}], 
     Plot[bt00, {t, tk[[1]], tk[[6]]}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}], PlotRange -> All]
Show[ListPlot[Transpose[{tk, ck}], PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}], 
     Plot[ct00, {t, tk[[1]], tk[[6]]}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks good, but it is not faster, right? Any ideas on how to make it faster?

Comment: Note that what is delayed is the symbolic resolution of the differential equation and that, for a fixed number of points, is only done once. The minimization process is  quite fast.

Comment: I understand, but it does not seem faster than mine. Besides, which Mathematica version are you using? Mine is 13.3.0 (Windows) and running your code exactly I get [this](https://imgur.com/a/d0GE8GI). Also, why use a custom-made interpolation?

Comment: My MATHEMATICA 12.0.0.0 running under Linux Ubuntu. It runs giving the shown results. In your process which is delayed is the `NonlinearModelFit`command. In my version this is quite fast: also the custom-made interpolation is to facilitate the symbolic resolution.

Comment: If you intent to process a large number of similar cases, in my version, the needed time is 5000*`Minimize` command.

Comment: Could you facilitate the data set which gave the results you show me?

Comment: I am using the same data as you. I simply copied your answer, without any alteration

Comment: I made again a copy/paste from the OP and it runs giving the same published results. I have no explanation for this. Sorry.

Comment: Weird indeed. I will try it in version 12.0.0. Can you give me an estimate of how long it takes to run with your approach?

Comment: `{b[t], c[t]} /. DSolve[ode, {b, c}, t][[1]]` needs 22.9893 absolute time and `Minimize[obj, {k1, k2, p1, p2, u[1], u[0], u[2], u[3], u[4], u[5],  u[6], b0, c0}]` needs 1.32789

Comment: It worked in 12.0.0! How strange, any idea why it's so slow in 13.2.0? Would you like to try it?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a license for version 13.

Comment: Just two more questions: can you implement some type of `MaxIterations` in your version of the code so we can tweak it to achieve even higher speed? Also, if I rescale the data by `*1000` for each `ak`, `bk` and `ck`, I get some [strange results](https://imgur.com/a/CVbt1WI). Any idea why?

Comment: Finally, your fitting and interpolation do not impose non-negativity. Any easy way to fix this?

Comment: First, I doubt that it is the way in which it treats the steps in the composition of the `interp` function. I'll try to use that same interpolation by using `Piecewise` to see what happens. The nonnegativity can be handled in the minimization restrictions. I will have a look ASAP.

Comment: The restrictions are already included.

Comment: I'm afraid I still get negative values for time greater than 35 (approximately). Could this be related to the interpolation?

Comment: I really like your approach, but I cannot use accept yet without dealing with the non-negativity. Either way, I might transition to Python for this specific problem, as `lmfit` seems quite optimal for this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77587951/how-to-fit-a-system-of-odes-with-interpolation) for an implementation there. Would it be easy to implement a custom version of the interpolation in Python, like you did here?

Comment: Apologies, I have only just noticed that you fixed it already. Still, if you have insights into transitioning this to Python, as per my previous comment, it would be great :) Thank you, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has 4 parameters, and only 6 x 3 = 18 data points. I suspect that this problem is only weakly determined, if you consider the ["Rule of 10"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_in_ten_rule) which states that you should have 10 data points for each parameter that you are trying to fit.

If you sequentially:

1. fit,
2. take final parameters from 1) and re-fit,
3. then fit again with parameters from 2)

you will see that the plots are virtually the same, despite the fact that the optimized parameter sets 1), 2), 3) are quite different.

Answering your question directly, how to speed this up, I don't have a good answer, because I feel that this is a weakly-determined system and the optimizer is going to hop around on a rather shallow likelihood surface.

I have fitted these sorts of equations with similar data paucity using Markov chain Monte Carlo.  In my problems, the parameter uncertainties are rather large.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, somehow even something as an improved first guess would be helpful, as long as it can be used to speed up the fitting (I am ultimately interested in fitting 5000 independent systems of this kind, but it is impossibly slow as of the current implementation). And I agree with Tim, explaining the Monte Carlo approach would be extremely useful!